# Round decimal values in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Im trying to round this value : `0.0832500`

Should be `0.084`.

I use `ROUND`, `CEIL` and `FLOOR` and dont have succes, what do I have to do?

Comment: What if the number was 0.011? What would you expect the output to be?

Answer (score 2):

You want to round up to the Nth decimal. One option is:

```
ceil(0.0832500 * 1000) / 1000
```

Comment: Tks @GMB i have success with this!

Comment: Maybe divide by `1000.0` instead of `1000`?

Comment: @TheImpaler: mysql does not do integer division, so no issue here.